# Users cannot edit "Assigned To" field in Events

Tags: lightning, user, event, calendar

Salesforce pushed some updates over the weekend that are causing issues I haven't run in to before. Users are not able to edit the **Assigned To** field on Events after the changes. The error they are receiving says "you don't have access to assign events to this calendar. ask your admin to increase your sharing access level for this calendar salesforce"

I can't figure out what I've missed:

Calendar OWD sharing settings are already **Show Details and Add Events**.
User Profiles already have **Edit Tasks** and **Edit Events** permissions.
When I try to manually share a User's calendar it says the OWD are already set to show details and add events.

What am I missing??

Comment: Can you confirm if the profiles having issues have field-level edit access to Assigned To on the Event?

Comment: No issues with field-level access. I show the profiles I'm working with have read and edit access to the 'Assigned To' field

Comment: If you end up unable to get an answer here, I'd post in the Release Readiness Trailblazers group (https://trailhead.salesforce.com/trailblazer-community/groups/0F9300000001okuCAA?lang=en&tab=discussion) in case somebody else there has seen this behavior, and I'd open a support case.

Comment: I've already opened a support case but I'll check out that Trailblazers group as well. Thanks!